# Convert .nq (N-QUAD) file to .ttl (TURTLE)?

Tags: converters, file-type, turtle-rdf, n-quads

Currently there are many tools for RDF file type conversion. RDF2RDF, EasyRDF, and rrdf in R has some conversion functionalities. However, NONE of these conversion tools include converting .nq files to the other file types (.nt, .ttl, .rdf, .xml, etc).

I know N-QUAD is an N-TRIPLE file with just a 4th column, being the graph's IRI; however, there are many other considerations that need to be changed when converting from .nq to .nt.

I want to, ultimately, convert my .nq file to a .ttl file, including PREFIXs being declared at the beginning of the file. RDF2RDF doesn't seem to accommodate for prefix declarations. Is there a tool out there I don't know about that can help me do this?

Answer (score -1):

you can use [rdf2rdf](http://www.l3s.de/~minack/rdf2rdf/) to convert .nq to .ttl

Comment: Instead of posting links as answer add some text to explanation how this answer help to OP in fixing current issue.Thanks

Comment: This does not work. nQuads (nq) is not stated within the supported extensions of the referred library.

Comment: I understand the sentiment to down vote here, but this link is more than sufficient to follow in case someone is stick in a similar situation. thanks @archur